# How to find certain sequence in a huge list of sequences

Tags: python

```
P0C5Z8: MLGVINRMAKKFNYKLPSMVALTLVGSAVTAHQVQAAETTQDQTTNKNVLDSNKVKATTEQAKAEVKNPTQNISGTQVYQDPAIVQPKTANNKTGNAQVS
Q53630: MSNNFKDDFEKNRQSIDTNSHQDHTEDVEKDQSELEHQDTIENTEQQFPPRNAQRRKRRRDLATNHNKQVHNESQTSEDNVQNEAGTIDDRQVESSHSTE
P0C6P1: MKKKLLVLTMSTLFATQLINSNHANASVTESVDKKFVVPESGINKIIPTYNEFKKAPKVNVSNLTDNKNFVASEDKLKKISDPSAASKIVDKNFVVPESK
O69174: MPIITDVYAREVLDSRGNPTVEVEVLTESGAFGRALVPSGASTGEHEAVELRDGDKSRYLGKGVTKAVENVNEIIAPEIIEGEFSVLDQVSIDKMMIALD
P0A031: MLEFEQGFNHLATLKVIGVGGGGNNAVNRMIDHGMNNVEFIAINTDGQALNLSKAESKIQIGEKLTRGLGAGANPEIGKKAAEESREQIEDAIQGADMVF
P0C1S5: MTKHYLNSKYQSEQRSSAMKKITMGTASIILGSLVYIGADSQQVNAATEATNATNNQSTQVSQATSQPINFQVQKDGSSEKSHMDDYMQHPGKVIKQNNK
P0C1S0: MSDQHNLKEQLCFSLYNAQRQVNRYYSNKVFKKYNLTYPQFLVLTILWDESPVNVKKVVTELALDTGTVSPLLKRMEQVDLIKRERSEVDQREVFIHLTD
```

I have this list of sequence....but I want to know if this sequence (TGTCV) is evident in this whole list
How would I look for it with code?

Comment: use `string.find` function, it will return the index if it found otherwise return -1

Comment: What do you mean by evident???

Answer (score 3):

```
lol = """P0C5Z8: MLGVINRMAKKFNYKLPSMVALTLVGSAVTAHQVQAAETTQDQTTNKNVLDSNKVKATTEQAKAEVKNPTQNISGTQVYQDPAIVQPKTANNKTGNAQVS
Q53630: MSNNFKDDFEKNRQSIDTNSHQDHTEDVEKDQSELEHQDTIENTEQQFPPRNAQRRKRRRDLATNHNKQVHNESQTSEDNVQNEAGTIDDRQVESSHSTE
P0C6P1: MKKKLLVLTMSTLFATQLINSNHANASVTESVDKKFVVPESGINKIIPTYNEFKKAPKVNVSNLTDNKNFVASEDKLKKISDPSAASKIVDKNFVVPESK
O69174: MPIITDVYAREVLDSRGNPTVEVEVLTESGAFGRALVPSGASTGEHEAVELRDGDKSRYLGKGVTKAVENVNEIIAPEIIEGEFSVLDQVSIDKMMIALD
P0A031: MLEFEQGFNHLATLKVIGVGGGGNNAVNRMIDHGMNNVEFIAINTDGQALNLSKAESKIQIGEKLTRGLGAGANPEIGKKAAEESREQIEDAIQGADMVF
P0C1S5: MTKHYLNSKYQSEQRSSAMKKITMGTASIILGSLVYIGADSQQVNAATEATNATNNQSTQVSQATSQPINFQVQKDGSSEKSHMDDYMQHPGKVIKQNNK
P0C1S0: MSDQHNLKEQLCFSLYNAQRQVNRYYSNKVFKKYNLTYPQFLVLTILWDESPVNVKKVVTELALDTGTVSPLLKRMEQVDLIKRERSEVDQREVFIHLTD"""

print "TGTCV" in lol
```

Comment: So cool! Never knew it was possible. Now I have one more reason to love Python

Comment: powerful one liner...loved it

Answer (score 1):

By simply using `string.count`:

```
>>> string.count('TGTCV')
0
```

Or try using regex

```
>>> regex = re.compile("TGTCV")
>>> r = regex.search(string)
# Run findall
>>> print len(regex.findall(string)) # count of 'TGTCV'
0
```